# Parsing Json - from sql (Aurora) to aws lambda

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

i am not able to parse a json as is from sql to lambda. Lets say below is my stored procedure that calls lambda api.

```
CALL mysql.lambda_async('arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<account_id>:function:<sample_name>',  <---- this should be your lambda function ARN
     CONCAT('{ "message_id" : "', 'test.txt', 
            '", "transaction_json" : "', '{"glossary": {
                                                "title": "example glossary",
                                                    "GlossDiv": {
                                                        "title": "S",
                                                        "GlossList": {
                                                            "GlossEntry": {
                                                                "ID": "SGML",
                                                                "SortAs": "SGML",
                                                                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                                                                "Acronym": "SGML",
                                                                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                                                                "GlossDef": {
                                                                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                                                                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                                                                },
                                                                "GlossSee": "markup"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }}}',
                '", "s3_bucket" : "', 'br-gtosbx-gtps-data-useast-1-s3',
            '"}'));
```

Now this will call a lambda function which is written in python 3.6

```
def s3_publish_message(event, context):
    import boto3
    import botocore
    import json

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    s3_bucket = event['s3_bucket']
    #transaction_json = event['transaction_json']
    try:
        event_str = str(json.dumps(event['transaction_json'])).encode("utf-8")
        print("s3 Load Completed")
    except Exception as err:
        print("Could not convert event to string for storage. Threw exception: {}".format(err))

    message_id = event['message_id']

    s3.put_object(ACL='private',
                        Body=event_str,
                        Bucket=s3_bucket,
                        StorageClass='STANDARD',
                        Tagging='test',
                        Key=message_id)
```

when i run the stored procedure in mysql i get below error.

```
Error Code: 1873. Lambda API returned error: Invalid Request Content. Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character ('g' (code 103)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries  at [Source: [B@616b0a0f; line: 1, column: 55]
```

is there any way i can handle this or should we send json without (")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't embed a JSON object into a JSON string this way.  You can do it, but not the way you are doing it.  It simply doesn't work that way.

But also, you shouldn't need to.

JSON is an *object serialization* format -- it takes logical objects and represents them in a character-based string.  It is commonly used between disparate systems to allow an object to be transported via a medium -- like HTTP -- that has no intrinsic concept of an "object" with key/value pairs, arrays, and strings.

Your entire second argument to `mysql.lambda_async()` is JSON.  You're telling it that `transaction_json` is a *string*, rather than simply a nested object.

```
"transaction_json" : "{"glossary": ...
```

This is wrong, because if it is a string, then it is not properly encoded as a *JSON string* because JSON strings cannot contain unescaped `"` as well as some other characters.

But there is no need to do that.  Just remove the outer quotes.

Take everything you are passing to the second argument to `mysql.lambda_async()` and paste it into a validator like http://jsonlint.com and you will see that it is indeed invalid JSON.

Remove the `"` surrounding the transaction_json value, and the object will be valid.

```
'", "transaction_json" : "', '{"glossary # old 
'", "transaction_json" : {"glossary      # new
```

...and...

```
'", "s3_bucket" : "', 'br-gtosbx-gtps-data-useast-1-s3', # old      
', "s3_bucket" : "', 'br-gtosbx-gtps-data-useast-1-s3',  # new
```

But also, you have technically misnamed this field.  It is not transaction *JSON*.  It is simply the transaction *object*.  The outer container is JSON, the inner value is not.

With the outer quotes removed, `event_str = str(json.dumps(event['transaction_json'])).encode("utf-8")` should not be needed, because `event['transaction_json']` *is already an object* -- Lambda will have deserialied the entire event structure.